# How to disable quartz load balancing?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have this scheduler :

```
<bean id="odilQuartzScheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
    lazy-init="false">
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="schedulerName" value="OdilScheduler"/>
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="${popo.scheduler}"/>
    <property name="startupDelay" value="60"/>
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz-odil.properties"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="applicationTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="globalConfiguration" value-ref="globalConfiguration"/>
            <entry key="odilFileImporter" value-ref="odilFileImporter"/>
            <entry key="odilRemoteDispatcher" value-ref="odilRemoteDispatcher"/>
            <entry key="odilService" value-ref="odilService"/>
            <entry key="centreReferenceService" value-ref="centreReferenceService"/>
            <entry key="envoiParserFactory" value-ref="envoiParserFactory"/>
            <entry key="versionReferenceService" value-ref="versionReferenceService"/>
            <entry key="delPublisherService" value-ref="delPublisherService"/>
            <entry key="capteurPublisherService" value-ref="capteurPublisherService"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="piloteOdilTrigger-1"/>
            <ref bean="piloteOdilTrigger-2"/>
            <ref bean="piloteOdilTrigger-3"/>
            <ref bean="piloteOdilTrigger-4"/>
            <ref bean="piloteOdilTrigger-5"/>
            <ref bean="piloteOdilTrigger-6"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="piloteOdilTrigger-1" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="name" value="Trigger 1"/>
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="piloteOdilJobBean1"/>
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="60000"/>
    <property name="group" value="POPO"/>
</bean>
<bean id="piloteOdilTrigger-2" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="name" value="Trigger 2"/>
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="piloteOdilJobBean2"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${popo.odil.rushhour.cronexpression}" />
    <property name="group" value="POPO"/>
</bean>
<bean id="piloteOdilTrigger-3" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="name" value="Trigger 3"/>
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="piloteOdilJobBean3"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${popo.odil.rushhour.cronexpression}" />
    <property name="group" value="POPO"/>
</bean>
<bean id="piloteOdilTrigger-4" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="name" value="Trigger 4"/>
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="piloteOdilJobBean4"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${popo.odil.rushhour.cronexpression}" />
    <property name="group" value="POPO"/>
</bean>
<bean id="piloteOdilTrigger-5" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="name" value="Trigger 5"/>
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="piloteOdilJobBean5"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${popo.odil.rushhour.cronexpression}" />
    <property name="group" value="POPO"/>
</bean>
<bean id="piloteOdilTrigger-6" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="name" value="Trigger 6"/>
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="piloteOdilJobBean6"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${popo.odil.rushhour.cronexpression}" />
    <property name="group" value="POPO"/>
</bean>

<bean id="piloteOdilJobBean-template" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="name" value="Pilote ODIL"/>
    <property name="jobClass" value="fr.xxxx.popo.batch.PiloteOdilJob"/> <!-- implements StatefulJob -->
    <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true"/>
    <property name="group" value="POPO"/>
</bean>
<bean id="piloteOdilJobBean1" parent="piloteOdilJobBean-template" />
<bean id="piloteOdilJobBean2" parent="piloteOdilJobBean-template" />
<bean id="piloteOdilJobBean3" parent="piloteOdilJobBean-template" />
<bean id="piloteOdilJobBean4" parent="piloteOdilJobBean-template" />
<bean id="piloteOdilJobBean5" parent="piloteOdilJobBean-template" />
<bean id="piloteOdilJobBean6" parent="piloteOdilJobBean-template" />
```

this is it's configuration file

```
#============================================================================
# Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = OdilScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false

#============================================================================
# ThreadPool
#============================================================================
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 6
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

#============================================================================
# JobStore
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 3

#============================================================================
# Plugins
#============================================================================
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class = org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown = true
```

From what I understood using a ramJobStore make it non clusterable and thus load balancing should not work.

But in reallity when I have 2 servers running, each one has it's own OdilScheduler, with 6 triggers each.
However a total of only 6 trigger will work at the same time.
3 on instance 1 and 3 on instance 2 for example, I want all the 12 trigger to work simultaniously.

What am I missing?

Thanks

ps : quartz version : 1.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mislead, in fact I only tried with 3 trigger on each instance.
1 normal and 2 cron trigger.

The cron trigger were using the RAMJobStore, but because of the template, each trigger had the same name so each instance could only use 1 cron trigger (they are identified by their name).

Which is why it looked like load balancing was happening, in fact what was happening is that since they had the same name only one trigger was triggered per instance.

If I had set 5 cron trigger for each instance I would have had only 1 trigger per instance.